# Use an iMac as a network gateway Wi-Fi <---> Ethernet

Tags: networking, macos, router

I want to connect a Windows XP/PC to a network of two iMacs. 
(The PC doesn't have to connect to the Internet.)

The network, with static address, looks like:

> Internet ---> ADSL Box <--- Wi-Fi ---> iMac_2 <--- eth ---> PC

(iMac_2 and PC are connected directly with an Ethernet cable.)

**ADSL Box**

- IP 192.168.0.254

**iMac_2** (High Sierra)

- **Main service** - Wi-Fi (set with "Define order of service" of Network pref) IP : 192.168.0.2 SubnetMask : 255.255.255.0 Router :
  192.168.0.254
- **Second service** - Ethernet (set with "Define order of service" of Network pref) IP : 192.168.1.9 SubnetMask : 255.255.255.0 Router :
  192.168.0.254

**PC** - Ethernet

- IP : 192.168.1.11
- SubnetMask : 255.255.255.0
- Router : 192.168.1.9

The iMac_2 is networking fine (internet, file sharing with iMac_1, printer,…). 
The iMac_2 can see r/w the shared folder on the PC; it's ok. 
The PC can ping the iMac_2 at 192.168.1.9.

**The problems are:**

- The PC can't connect to the iMac_2 users: "The specified network name is no longer available".
- Every day the Ethernet IP of the iMac has to be changed (e.g., 192.168.1.8) and set back to the proper IP, or it can't connect with the PC.

The PC can't ping either the main iMac_2 IP interface 192.168.0.2 (where the iMac users are hosted is suppose) nor to the ADSL Box or iMac_1.

I understand that the problem came from the network setting of iMac _2 that does not enable NAT and doesn't use iMac_2 as a router.

Cross or straight Ethernet cord do the same result.

Does somebody have any bits of advice or tips?

PS: of course I did look at other posts with topics like mine,
but none give me the answer or I misunderstand something.

PS 2: the PC is using an "old" licensed software that I use regularly,
and all newer expensive update do not provide me any "plus". 
The XP system is out of date, but the software does the job.

PS 3: tried to use a CPL network with the PC,
but it interferes with my electricity provider’s own CPL check meter. 
UBS-Wi-Fi key work, very, very poorly.

Comment: Have you tried using Internet Sharing under System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing?

Comment: Yes i did. Sharing wireless connexion with Ethernet is on. The purpose is mainly to share flie and folder, not having an acces to internet.

Comment: The strange behaviour of the IP address on the iMac works perfect when "Sharing wireless connexion with Ethernet" is off .